# How to open PHPstan file URL in PhpStorm's terminal?

Tags: url, terminal, phpstorm, phpstan

Current situation: I'm using PhpStorm and PHPstan. I want to start analysis via PhpStorm and want the output in PhpStorm's terminal. So far so good, that's not a problem.

Now I want to use PHPstan's feature to output the files as URL (via `editorUrl: 'phpstorm://open?file=%%file%%&line=%%line%%'`). Using this config the correct string is printed in PhpStorm's terminal, but the URL is not intractable and is written out. When I use the command in a normal Linux terminal everything works as expected. But for workflows sake I would like this in PhpStorm's terminal.

Is there any way to tell PhpStorm's terminal to interpret the link? It works with normal https-links...

**Output - IDE-Terminal:**

[image: Output - IDE-Terminal]

**Output - Normal Terminal:**

[image: Output - Normal Terminal]

Comment: Unfortunately, PhpStorm terminal is unable to handle such type of links. As a sort of workaround it could have been the "file:///" protocol with the line no in "editorUrl" but line numbers are not supported as well:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221519/Support-file-links-with-lines

Comment: By the way, is there any specific reason why avoid using a built-in PHPStan integration support? In this case, you may use it for online checks on-the-fly or via the manual inspection run: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-phpstan.html

Comment: I am using built-in support too. But I integrated an old dependency and bc of that I have like 300 errors in different files. Searching all files manually is not the way to do this.
Thanks for ur answer though. 
I was afraid that there is no way solving this, but i saw it coming.